# Why is Neo4j not recognizing the degree centrality query?

Tags: neo4j, node-centrality

For some reason Neo4j is not recognizing degree centrality on a projection in GDS. I run this query:

```
CALL gds.degree.stream('influence_graph', { relationshipWeightProperty: 'score' })
YIELD nodeId, score
RETURN gds.util.asNode(nodeId).name AS name, score AS followers
ORDER BY followers DESC, name DESC
```

I then get this error message:

```
There is no procedure with the name `gds.degree.stream` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

That doesn't make sense to me because Neo4j says in its [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/degree-centrality/) that's what should be used. GDS is installed, and I've had no problem running other centrality measures -- PageRank, betweenness and closeness. I even tried doing a ctrl-c, ctrl-v right from the Neo4j documentation to ensure I wasn't mistyping something. Are there any other plugins that need to be installed? I have APOC and GDS installed but nothing else.

I realize degree is simple enough I could just do this via regular Cypher, but I'm curious why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of GDS do you have installed? The signature of the procedure might not match the documentation you are using. Run this query to check.

```
RETURN gds.version()
```

You can also run this query to see any procedure that you have installed that includes the word degree.

```
SHOW PROCEDURES YIELD name 
WHERE name CONTAINS 'degree'
RETURN name
ORDER BY name
```

If you have an older version of Neo4j, SHOW PROCEDURES is not supported. Use this query instead.

```
CALL dbms.procedures() YIELD name
WHERE name CONTAINS 'degree'
RETURN name
ORDER BY name
```

Degree centrality was promoted to the product tier with GDS version 1.6.0. If you are using an older version of GDS, you should refer to this documentation. https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/1.1/algorithms/degree-centrality/

Comment: I have version 1.4.1 For some reason the query you provided isn't working. I'm getting this error: Invalid input 'O': expected 'i/I' (line 1, column 8 (offset: 7))
"SHOW PROCEDURES YIELD name" I've tried subbing in algorithms I know are there (i.e. "louvain") but still get the same error.

Comment: I'm actually wondering if there's a bug. Neo4j's documentation says SHOW PROCEDURES YIELD * or SHOW PROCEDURES should show all procedures, but I'm getting the same error -- even when I ctrl-c, ctrl-v right from the documentation.

Comment: Yes, SHOW PROCEDURES is a newer way to get the list of procedures that is not supported in older versions of neo4j. I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: There is a drop down in the upper right corner of the Neo4j documentation pages that will let you switch to the content that matches your Neo4j version.

Comment: Thanks. I'll make sure to update further once I'm done with this project. Desktop is at 1.4.9, which is saying no further updates. But the database version is at 4.2.1 compared to the latest at 4.3.7. I don't want to risk breaking something until I can wrap this one thing up.

Comment: Also: Thanks a ton for the tip on the version dropdown on the Neo4j documentation. It's little things like that that are hugely helpful!